# How to get attributes of form element with ngForm?

Tags: angular

I defined some ngForms in the component's template:

```html
<form #myForm="ngForm" name="a" id="a" data-id="a">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" [ngModel]="a"/>
</form>
 
<form #myForm="ngForm" name="b" id="b" data-id="b">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" [ngModel]="b"/>
</form>
```

I want to iterate over the forms on the component's controller and get a reference to the "identification" of the form, but how can I get either the name or id of the form element? There is some other way without having to define a "dummy" hidden input named "id"?

```js
@ViewChildren('myForm') myForms: QueryList<NgForm>;
 
this.myForms.forEach(form => {
  // form.name = undefined
  // form.xxx.id -> how? nope!
  // form.xxx.dataset -> how? nope!
  form.value.id // this way works, but it sucks :)
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to search form as ElementRefs

```js
export class AppComponent implements AfterViewInit {
  @ViewChildren('formElem', {read: ElementRef}) myFormElems: QueryList<ElementRef>;
 
  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    this.myFormElems.forEach((form: ElementRef) => {
      const formElement = form.nativeElement;
      console.log(formElement.name);
      console.log(formElement.getAttribute('id'));
      console.log(formElement.dataset.id);
  });
  }
}
```

```html
<form #formElem #myForm="ngForm" name="a" id="a" data-id="a">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="a"/>
</form>
 
<form #formElem #myForm="ngForm" name="b" id="b" data-id="b">
 <input type="hidden" name="id" value="b"/>
</form>
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ufkmsg?file=src/app/app.component.html

Comment: Yeah, the problem of this way is, I cannot access the ngForm on the loop.